# Building LLVM Kaleidoscope tutorial language with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, llvm

### Setup

I've been working through the [LLVM frontend tutorial](https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/MyFirstLanguageFrontend/index.html) which has been great. Using the `clang++` commands directly are working fine but I'd like to move to CMake to learn a bit more about the config process. Here's my setup:

System details:

```
M1 Macbook
Monterey 12.6
llvm 15.0.2 installed via homebrew
cmake 3.24.2 installed via homebrew
```

Project structure:

```
build/
src/
  -| main.cpp
CMakeLists.txt
```

`main.cpp` is copy-paste from the code [sample here](https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/MyFirstLanguageFrontend/LangImpl04.html#full-code-listing).

Clang command:

```
clang++ -g src/main.cpp `llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --system-libs --libs core orcjit native` -O3 -o build/toy
```

CMake file (adapted from the [llvm example](https://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html#embedding-llvm-in-your-project)):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13.4)

project(SimpleProject)

find_package(LLVM REQUIRED CONFIG)

message(STATUS "Found LLVM ${LLVM_PACKAGE_VERSION}")
message(STATUS "Using LLVMConfig.cmake in: ${LLVM_DIR}")
message(STATUS "Using LLVMConfig.cmake in: ${LLVM_CMAKE_DIR}")

# Set your project compile flags.
# E.g. if using the C++ header files
# you will need to enable C++11 support
# for your compiler.
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

include_directories(${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS})
separate_arguments(LLVM_DEFINITIONS_LIST NATIVE_COMMAND ${LLVM_DEFINITIONS})
add_definitions(${LLVM_DEFINITIONS_LIST})

message(STATUS "LLVM DEF LIST: ${LLVM_DEFINITIONS_LIST}")
message(STATUS "LLVM INCLUDE DIRS: ${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS}")

# Now build our tools
add_executable(simple-tool src/main.cpp)

# Find the libraries that correspond to the LLVM components
# that we wish to use
llvm_map_components_to_libnames(llvm_libs core orcjit native)

message(STATUS "LLVM_LIBS: ${llvm_libs}")

# Link against LLVM libraries
target_link_libraries(simple-tool ${llvm_libs})
```

### Problem

To build I've been doing:

```bash
cd build
CC=clang CXX=clang++ cmake ..
cmake --build .
```

But it always fails, it's clear that the llvm libs are not being linked correctly, but I'm not sure how to get that working. My `llvm_map_components_to_libnames` is 1:1 with the clang++ command libs. I've double checked other env flags and altered paths to try and make sure the `llvm` homebrew directories are included but nothing has worked. I'm pretty new to CMake so I'm guessing that's where the mistake is.

Output for cmake + cmake build:

```
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 15.0.2
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 15.0.2
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/clang - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/clang++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Performing Test HAVE_FFI_CALL
-- Performing Test HAVE_FFI_CALL - Success
-- Found FFI: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/lib/libffi.tbd  
-- Performing Test Terminfo_LINKABLE
-- Performing Test Terminfo_LINKABLE - Success
-- Found Terminfo: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/lib/libcurses.tbd  
-- Found ZLIB: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/lib/libz.tbd (found version "1.2.11") 
-- Found LibXml2: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/lib/libxml2.tbd (found version "2.9.4") 
-- Found LLVM 15.0.2
-- Using LLVMConfig.cmake in: /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/lib/cmake/llvm
-- Using LLVMConfig.cmake in: /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/lib/cmake/llvm
-- LLVM DEF LIST: -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS;-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS;-D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS
-- LLVM INCLUDE DIRS: /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/include
-- LLVM_LIBS: LLVMCore;LLVMOrcJIT;LLVMAArch64CodeGen;LLVMAArch64AsmParser;LLVMAArch64Desc;LLVMAArch64Disassembler;LLVMAArch64Info;LLVMAArch64Utils
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: <project_path>/build
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/simple-tool.dir/src/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable simple-tool
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_LLVMInitializeAMDGPUAsmParser", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllAsmParsers() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeAMDGPUAsmPrinter", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllAsmPrinters() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeAMDGPUTarget", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllTargets() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeAMDGPUTargetInfo", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllTargetInfos() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeAMDGPUTargetMC", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllTargetMCs() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeARMAsmParser", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllAsmParsers() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeARMAsmPrinter", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllAsmPrinters() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeARMTarget", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllTargets() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeARMTargetInfo", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllTargetInfos() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeARMTargetMC", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllTargetMCs() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeAVRAsmParser", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllAsmParsers() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeAVRAsmPrinter", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllAsmPrinters() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeAVRTarget", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllTargets() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeAVRTargetInfo", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllTargetInfos() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeAVRTargetMC", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllTargetMCs() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeBPFAsmParser", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllAsmParsers() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeBPFAsmPrinter", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllAsmPrinters() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeBPFTarget", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllTargets() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeBPFTargetInfo", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllTargetInfos() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeBPFTargetMC", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllTargetMCs() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeHexagonAsmParser", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllAsmParsers() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeHexagonAsmPrinter", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllAsmPrinters() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeHexagonTarget", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllTargets() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeHexagonTargetInfo", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllTargetInfos() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeHexagonTargetMC", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllTargetMCs() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeLanaiAsmParser", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllAsmParsers() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeLanaiAsmPrinter", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllAsmPrinters() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeLanaiTarget", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllTargets() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeLanaiTargetInfo", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllTargetInfos() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeLanaiTargetMC", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllTargetMCs() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeMSP430AsmParser", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllAsmParsers() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeMSP430AsmPrinter", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllAsmPrinters() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeMSP430Target", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllTargets() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeMSP430TargetInfo", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllTargetInfos() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeMSP430TargetMC", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllTargetMCs() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeMipsAsmParser", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllAsmParsers() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeMipsAsmPrinter", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllAsmPrinters() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeMipsTarget", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllTargets() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeMipsTargetInfo", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllTargetInfos() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeMipsTargetMC", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllTargetMCs() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeNVPTXAsmPrinter", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllAsmPrinters() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeNVPTXTarget", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllTargets() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeNVPTXTargetInfo", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllTargetInfos() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeNVPTXTargetMC", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllTargetMCs() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializePowerPCAsmParser", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllAsmParsers() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializePowerPCAsmPrinter", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllAsmPrinters() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializePowerPCTarget", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllTargets() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializePowerPCTargetInfo", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllTargetInfos() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializePowerPCTargetMC", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllTargetMCs() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeRISCVAsmParser", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllAsmParsers() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeRISCVAsmPrinter", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllAsmPrinters() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeRISCVTarget", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllTargets() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeRISCVTargetInfo", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllTargetInfos() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeRISCVTargetMC", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllTargetMCs() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeSparcAsmParser", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllAsmParsers() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeSparcAsmPrinter", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllAsmPrinters() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeSparcTarget", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllTargets() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeSparcTargetInfo", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllTargetInfos() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeSparcTargetMC", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllTargetMCs() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeSystemZAsmParser", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllAsmParsers() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeSystemZAsmPrinter", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllAsmPrinters() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeSystemZTarget", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllTargets() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeSystemZTargetInfo", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllTargetInfos() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeSystemZTargetMC", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllTargetMCs() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeVEAsmParser", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllAsmParsers() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeVEAsmPrinter", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllAsmPrinters() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeVETarget", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllTargets() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeVETargetInfo", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllTargetInfos() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeVETargetMC", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllTargetMCs() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeWebAssemblyAsmParser", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllAsmParsers() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeWebAssemblyAsmPrinter", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllAsmPrinters() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeWebAssemblyTarget", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllTargets() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeWebAssemblyTargetInfo", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllTargetInfos() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeWebAssemblyTargetMC", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllTargetMCs() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeX86AsmParser", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllAsmParsers() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeX86AsmPrinter", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllAsmPrinters() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeX86Target", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllTargets() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeX86TargetInfo", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllTargetInfos() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeX86TargetMC", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllTargetMCs() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeXCoreAsmPrinter", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllAsmPrinters() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeXCoreTarget", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllTargets() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeXCoreTargetInfo", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllTargetInfos() in main.cpp.o
  "_LLVMInitializeXCoreTargetMC", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeAllTargetMCs() in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang-15: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [simple-tool] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/simple-tool.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any help is appreciated and let me know if there's more info I can provide!